# How to remove roles from members with a 1 second interval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
targets.forEach(member => member.roles.remove(role))
```

Since I am worried about hitting the rate limit, can it be done in such a way that, the role is removed at an interval of 1 second per member? I've defined 'role' and 'targets'.
I have completed the project, but couldn't figure out how to add the interval of 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you can schedule events using the setInterval or setTimeout functions.

```
var index = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
   if (index < targets.length - 1)
      targets[index].roles.remove(role);
   else
     clearInterval(myInterval);

   index++;
}, 1000);
```

The 1000 is the milliseconds between times the loop runs.  Also I noticed you did roles.remove even though your text says add.

Edit:  I realized I forgot to increment index so I added it.

Comment: While more difficult to read, this is answer scales better. `setTimeout` places each callback onto the stack, which has limited size. A huge number of setTimeouts will crash your application.

Comment: Yeah fixed the. Question. It's remove.

Comment: Yup. This worked. Since I had a large set of targets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- use `setTimeout`. And offset each timeout by using the index of each role.

```
targets.forEach((member, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     member.roles.remove(role)
  }, i*1000);
});
```

Comment: There is an extra ) after (role).

Comment: I get this in the console. Timeout overflow warning: (A long number) does not fit into a 32 bit signed integer.